# Word describing that something is a characteristic unique to something else. Used with +to

Tags: single-word-requests

I've lost an English word that is usually used with "to", and that means: "is a unique characteristic of something", or "is used only in connection with something".

We would use it in a sentence like this:

> Wings are not <...> to birds, you can find them among insects and unicorns.

Which would mean

*Wings are not only inherent to birds, you can find them among insects and unicorns.*

or

*Wings are not unique to birds...*

or

*Wings are not exclusive to birds...*

"Only inherent to" is not the one because it's three words instead of two. *Unique* or *exclusive* are not the ones because with them "to birds" is redundant, and this particular word requires an object.

Comment: I don't see how "unique" or "exclusive" make "to birds" redundant. My first thought when reading your initial question was definitely "exclusive to".

Comment: You could use "**peculiar to**" but it is not really an improvement over "unique" or "exclusive"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest **confined to**.

> If something is confined to a particular group of people, it exists
> only among them:
>
> - *Cancer is not confined to old people.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confine)]

> - *Parrotlike beaks are not confined to the sauropsid amniotes, however, as in the Permian a group of dicynodontid therapsids* ....

[[Comvergent Evolution; McGhee](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QwDSr1qdqXUC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22beaks+are+not+confined+to%22&source=bl&ots=Ekc5PtHlso&sig=ACfU3U0DbmlnfhiYLGita5tq_gzOSkIWHw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPus_MstX3AhVKOMAKHXN2C5kQ6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=%22beaks%20are%20not%20confined%20to%22&f=false)]

Answer (score 0):

> Wings are not **limited to** birds; you can find them among insects
> and unicorns.

> **limit *something* to *something***
>
> To restrict something to a limited set, a certain amount, or a
> specific number of something.
>
> *Please **limit** your comments **to** five
> minutes.*
> *Can you **limit** your remarks **to** the subject at hand?*
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/limited+to)

---

> Beaks are not **limited to** birds. [Sandra Alters; *Biology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Biology/GRDUIbQwGc8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=feathers%20are%20not%20limited%20to%20birds&pg=PA708&printsec=frontcover) (2002)

> Such to-and-fro movements are not **limited to** birds, but occur also
> in organisms as diverse as aphids and whales. [Hugh Dingle;
> *Migration*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Migration/3EduBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22are%20not%20limited%20to%20birds%22&pg=PT210&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Besides being extremely prolific, they [red mites] can exist months
> without eating, and are not **limited to** birds , but pass to man and
> quadrupeds. [Franklane Sewell; *The Poultry Manual*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Poultry_Manual/0ytLAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22are%20not%20limited%20to%20birds%22&pg=PA124&printsec=frontcover) (1908)